# var = input() breaks, but only sometimes

Tags: python, user-input

Alright. I am trying to make a bot what will request info from documents distributed by my school. and then send that info off to a discord api. however these documents will also have a bunch of useless info. I want to have an input() ask me what day I want to be looking at. but it spits out the error

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

It gets even more confusing when the code works sometimes. depending on what i have the document saved under. and how many times I've used it

code with some bits hidden for privacy

```
import requests
import urllib.request

#get html
fp = urllib.request.urlopen("https://docs.google.com/document/d/LinkIsKindaPrivate/edit")
mybytes = fp.read()
input = str(mybytes.decode("utf8"))

#give the bot where to look
curDay0 = input()
curDay1 = int(curDay0) * 3 + 1

#scrub through the html
scrub000 = input.split("Homework")
ls = len(scrub000[0])
scrub001 = input.split("Although it is not")
xs = len(scrub001[0])
in00 = input[ls:xs]
in01 = in00.split(r"\n\u")
in02 = in01[curDay1].replace("001c", "")
output = in02

#post it to discord
url = "https://discord.com/api/webhooks/WebhookAdress/WebhookAdress"
r = requests.post(url, data={"content": output})
fp.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are typing

```
curDay0 = input()
```

I think the error raises this line.

Or course, you define a variable `input` a few lines ago:

```
input = str(mybytes.decode("utf8"))
```

The line `curDay0 = input()` is trying to call a `str` text...

### So

rename your `input` variable into, I don't know, `input_`, or `url_content` for example. Your code should look like this:

```py
import requests
import urllib.request

#get html
fp = urllib.request.urlopen("https://docs.google.com/document/d/LinkIsKindaPrivate/edit")
mybytes = fp.read()
url_content = str(mybytes.decode("utf8"))

#give the bot where to look
curDay0 = input()
curDay1 = int(curDay0) * 3 + 1

#scrub through the html
scrub000 = url_content.split("Homework")
ls = len(scrub000[0])
scrub001 = url_content.split("Although it is not")
xs = len(scrub001[0])
in00 = url_content[ls:xs]
in01 = in00.split(r"\n\u")
in02 = in01[curDay1].replace("001c", "")
output = in02

#post it to discord
url = "https://discord.com/api/webhooks/WebhookAdress/WebhookAdress"
r = requests.post(url, data={"content": output})
fp.close()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I think its really cool someone took time out of their day to help me. Hopefully if I get some what better I can help someone else. :)

Comment: You're welcome - this is actually the goal of SO ^^